When I press edit, the to-do-list item disappears, and when I press delete, the id todo-lists disappears
I'm trying to create a simple to-do list app to practice JS. Each to-do-list has two buttons, and the button behavior I'm trying to implement via event deregulation. However, when I press edit, the to-do-list item disappears, and when I press delete, the id todo-lists disappears.


const form = document.getElementById("form");
const wrapper = document.getElementById("todo-lists");

function handleTodo(e) {
  const btn = e.target.closest("button");
  if (!btn) return; //not button
  const todo = e.currentTarget; // todo generated by sumit()

  if (btn.innerText === "remove") {
    wrapper.remove(todo);
  } else if (btn.innerText === "edit") {
    const todo_text = todo.querySelector("div");
    const new_input = document.createElement("input");
    new_input.value = todo_text.innerText;
    todo.prepend(new_input);
    todo.remove(todo_text);
  }
}

function submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = form.elements["todo_input"].value;
  const todo = document.createElement("div");

  todo.addEventListener("click", handleTodo);

  const todo_text = document.createElement("div");
  const del = document.createElement("button");
  const edit = document.createElement("button");
  del.innerText = "remove";
  edit.innerText = "edit";
  todo_text.innerText = value;

  todo.appendChild(todo_text);
  todo.appendChild(del);
  todo.appendChild(edit);
  wrapper.appendChild(todo);
  e.target.elements["todo_input"].value = "";
}

form.addEventListener("submit", submit);
<div id="container">
  <div id="todo-lists"></div>
  <div id="form-wrapper">
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter todo" name="todo_input" />
      <button>Enter</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>




This is the result of e.target and e.currentTarget of handleTodo Function.
and i leave the codepen address where you want to run this code.
https://codepen.io/gmjjfjnm-the-flexboxer/pen/RwOJggQ
I took a look at the console log and read the documentation on event delegation, but I couldn't find the correct answer.

Never mind, I was wrong. .closest() includes the element itself.

with wrapper.remove(todo) You are removing the entire wrapper element from the DOM, not just the specific todo item. Use todo.remove() instead and also the problem with the edit button you are using todo.remove(todo_text) use this indead todo_text.remove() so that you don't remove the entire todo

It looks like you're confusing .remove() with .removeChild().

parent.removeChild(child) is the old way, child.remove() is the newer, simpler way.

thank you. I took this opportunity to clearly understand the difference between remove() and removeChild(). Using wrapper.removeChild(todo) with "btn.innerText === 'remove'" and todo.removeChild(todo_text) for edit worked fine. thank you very much. I can finally sleep.

There are still several problems with your code tho, For example when you try to edit changes in one of the todos, you are trying to trying to access a div element innerText.
new_input.value = todo_text.innerText; The div element doesn't exist at that time becuz it was replaced by an input so you will get an error here.

I put the innerText value into new_input as new_input.value = todo_text.innerText; and then removed the div with todo.removeChild(todo_text). Any actual behavior is working fine. I'm wondering from what perspective you thought the error would occur.

When you press edit once on an existing todo. Your div is replaced by an input so that you can edit the todo's value but try pressing the edit button again to save the changes and see what happens. I'm asuming that should save changes on the current todo since there is no save button. If not then that is missing in your code

Thank you for your good point. However, not all functionality is complete yet, but that question was posted in the process of testing whether the inputs display well when pressing the delete and edit buttons. Rather, I wasn't able to complete all the features, but I apologize for asking a confusing question.

I have implemented a save button in the answer below.

The comments seem to have solved your core problems, anyway... I have implemented a save button on edit.


const form = document.getElementById("form");
const wrapper = document.getElementById("todo-lists");

function handleTodo(e) {
  const btn = e.target.closest("button");
  if (!btn) return; //not button
  const todo = e.currentTarget; // todo generated by sumit()

  if (btn.innerText === "remove") {
    wrapper.removeChild(todo);
  }

  if (btn.innerText === "edit") {
    const todo_text = todo.querySelector("div");
    const new_input = document.createElement("input");
    new_input.value = todo_text.innerText;
    todo_text.remove()
    todo.prepend(new_input);
    btn.innerText = "save";

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

      if (!new_input.value) {
        console.log('Add some text');
        return;
      };
      const val = new_input.value;
      todo.replaceChildren();
      todo.appendChild(todo_text);
      const del = document.createElement("button");
      const edit = document.createElement("button");
      del.innerText = "remove";
      edit.innerText = "edit";
      todo.appendChild(todo_text);
      todo_text.innerText = val;
      todo.appendChild(del);
      todo.appendChild(edit);

    })
  }
}

function submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = form.elements["todo_input"].value;
  if (!value) {
    console.log('Add some text');
    return;
  };
  const todo = document.createElement("div");

  todo.addEventListener("click", handleTodo);

  const todo_text = document.createElement("div");
  const del = document.createElement("button");
  const edit = document.createElement("button");
  del.innerText = "remove";
  edit.innerText = "edit";
  todo_text.innerText = value;

  todo.appendChild(todo_text);
  todo.appendChild(del);
  todo.appendChild(edit);
  wrapper.appendChild(todo);
  e.target.elements["todo_input"].value = "";
}

form.addEventListener("submit", submit);
<div id="container">
  <div id="todo-lists"></div>
  <div id="form-wrapper">
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter todo" name="todo_input" />
      <button>Enter</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>



